# Can't understand why I'm receiving an error with codecept

Tags: php, testing, automated-tests, codeception

I'm writing a small test program where I want to reach login form and to fill it. However, I receive an error. 
[image]

Here's what I got in my code:

```
<?php

class loginCest
{
    public function frontpageWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {

        $I->wantTo("Create login test");
        $I->amOnPage('my link');
        $I->see("join");
        $I->fillField('.form-control', 'my_login');
    }
}
```

Comment: ___However, I receive an error.___ Could you share the error with us please

Comment: 1) loginCest: Create login test
 Test  tests\acceptance\loginCest.php:frontpageWorks
 Step  Fill field ".form-control","email"
 Fail  Form field by Label or CSS element with '.form-control' was not found.

Comment: have you tried a different selector than only the class? A strict locator even maybe? Like `$I->fillField(['name' => 'userIdentifier'], 'my_login');` - I guess codeceptions finds more than one element with `.form-control`, or even a non-input.

Comment: The error cites "Email" form field, which isn't in the shown test, not in the shown html. Maybe the error referrs to something different than you think?

Comment: The field requires email address, is there other command to enter for email?

Comment: Still need a help with this problem.

Comment: Solved. @Jeff's suggest worked

Comment: I made it an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I would try with a strict locator like:

```
$I->fillField(['name' => 'userIdentifier'], 'my_login');
```

because codeceptions might find more than one element (and even a non-input) with the class `.form-control`